# Flutter Provider - Trying to subscribe to Firestore collection before being logged in

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm setting up a MultiProvider in `main.dart` which fails due to Firestore restrictions.

`5.20.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at terms failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

After logging in on the simulator it eventually works but it fails when testing the app on a device.

How should this provider be set to take into consideration the user status?

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
      value: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged, // Provider here
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<Content>.value(
      value: Content(),
    ),
    StreamProvider<List<Tmodel>>.value(
      value: db.streamTerms(),
    ),
  ],

class DatabaseService {
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

  Stream<List<Tmodel>> streamTerms() {
    var ref = _db.collection('terms');
    return ref.snapshots().map((list) =>
        list.documents.map((doc) => Tmodel.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
  }

}
```

Comment: Missing or insufficient permissions mean there's some error in configuring the firestore for your app. So your SHA key might be wrong

Comment: You don't have to pass the raw firebase stream. You can pass more complex streams that has advanced logic

Comment: Can you give me an example please? Can I listen to the collection after being authenticated? Or what do you mean?